# Is there a command to copy a file to a random location?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am wanting to make a batch file that will copy itself to randomly selected locations around the computer. I would like it to not have to have any user input after the script has started running. Is there a command for this?

Thanks.

(Not intended for malicious purposes...)

Comment: what? "Not intended for malicious purposes..." lol

Comment: What fun is that? Why not just make this file copied to a random location that you describe? Just change directory into random folders at each level until you bottom out and start pasting? Of course, this wouldn't be for malicious purposes... ;)

Comment: No existing command for this. Why is this post allowed to live?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@CD C:\newfolder
@set count=0
@For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\newfolder\*.* /ad /s /b') Do (
    set /a count=!count!+1
@rem     If !Count! gtr 1 echo Num of folders
)

Set /a num=%random% %% %Count% + 1 
Echo %num%

@For /f "skip=%num% delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\newfolder\*.* /ad /s /b') Do (
Echo this is nth random folder
Echo Copy "%~dpnx0" "%%A"
Exit /b
)
pause
```

Should get you thinking. See `for /?`, `set /?`, `dir /?`, `copy /?`, `exit /?` and `setlocal /?`.